# AutoMapper one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am starting to use AutoMapper. What I want is to do the following one-to-many mapping:

```
public class EntityEstablishment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int NumberParking { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentImage { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentLogoForDesktop { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentLogoForMobile { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentMap { get; set; }
    public int WidthMap { get; set; }
    public int HeightMap { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } = "enabled";
    public bool AvailableToBooking { get; set; } = true;
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public EntityUser User { get; set; }
    public List<EntityEquipment> Equipments { get; set; }
    public List<EntityBookableArea> BookableAreas { get; set; }
    public List<EntityParking> Parkings { get; set; }
    public List<EntityBankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class EntityBookableArea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public BookableAreaType Type { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public int StoreyNumber { get; set; }
    public double ValueHour { get; set; }
    public double ValueMidday { get; set; }
    public double ValueDay { get; set; }
    public double ValueWeek { get; set; }
    public double ValueHalfMonth { get; set; }
    public double ValueMonth { get; set; }
    public double ValueSesion { get; set; }
    public double ValueHourByStall { get; set; }
    public double ValueMiddayByStall { get; set; }
    public double ValueDayByStall { get; set; }
    public double ValueWeekByStall { get; set; }
    public double ValueHalfMonthByStall { get; set; }
    public double ValueMonthByStall { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string BookableDays { get; set; }
    public string BookableClass { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public double TaxPercentage { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeEquipment { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeParking { get; set; }
    public string Coordinates { get; set; }
    public List<EntityBooking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
    public EntityEstablishment Establishment { get; set; }
}

public class EstablishmentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre es requerido.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La ubicacion es requerida.")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int NumberParking { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentImage { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentLogoForDesktop { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentLogoForMobile { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentMap { get; set; }
    public int WidthMap { get; set; }
    public int HeightMap { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } = "enabled";
    public bool AvailableToBooking { get; set; } = true;
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Administrador del establecimiento es requerido.")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public UserDto User { get; set; }
    public List<EquipmentDto> Equipments { get; set; }
    public List<ParkingDto> Parkings { get; set; }
    public List<BookableAreaDto> BookableAreas { get; set; }
    public List<BankAccountDto> BankAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

How can I map the one-to-many relationship to get the information from the establishment with the `BookableAreas`?

I was trying the following but I get a mapping error - can you guide me on the matter?

Thank you very much for any help.

```
CreateMap<EntityEstablishment, EstablishmentDto>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.BookableAreas, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BookableAreas))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Parkings, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Parkings))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Did you add mapping for `BookableAreaDto` and `ParkingDto` before the mapping you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it is already added it is mapping

Comment: Use `ForPath` instead of `ForMember`

Comment: Can you provide the error/exception message for the mapping error mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: with ForPath it also gives an error

Comment: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
EntityEstablishment -> EstablishmentDto
NordicaReservasApp.Server.DBModels.EntityEstablishment -> NordicaReservasApp.Shared.Dtos.EstablishmentDto

Type Map configuration:
EntityEstablishment -> EstablishmentDto
NordicaReservasApp.Server.DBModels.EntityEstablishment -> NordicaReservasApp.Shared.Dtos.EstablishmentDto

Destination Member:
BookableAreas

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Comment: Do you register ` automapper`  in `startup.cs` class? if yes please provide startup.cs and automapper profile where you put `CreateMap` in your question

Comment: services.AddAutoMapper(config => config.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfiles>()); CreateMap<BookableAreaDto, EntityBookableArea>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<ParkingDto, EntityParking>().ReverseMap();CreateMap<EntityEstablishment, EstablishmentDto>()
               .ForPath(dest => dest.BookableAreas, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BookableAreas))
               .ForPath(dest => dest.Parkings, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Parkings));